# How to show data in rows looks like column like

Tags: jquery, html, css

[My broken function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqnHx.png)

Hello sorry for my broken English.

how to move that end of data cell in first row to first row of 2nd column. In a adding function its only adding tbody < td > example < td > so it only goes in first rows and any idea on looks like in top of this [Image bottom one is now want to looks like top one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJFT4.png)?.

```
$(".chkbox").click(function(){
  var value = $(this).val(),$list=$("#tablebody");
  if(this.click){
    $list.append("<td data-value='"+ value + "'>"+ value + "</td>")
    $(this).remove();       
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you want to remove that data, or add it to the next row of the table?

Comment: dont wanna remove just move to 1st row of 2nd column i have almost hundred of data to show in 4 row and that much column

Comment: share rest of the code too: html and css

Comment: Can some one delete this question because i got another one exact same caused by network problem kinda :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".chkbox").click(function() {
var value = $(this).val(),
Idans = $(this).attr('id'),
$list = $("#tablebody"),
$lastRow = $list.find("tr").last(),
if ($lastRow.length === 0 || $lastRow.find("td").length >= columnCount) {
$lastRow = $("<tr></tr>").appendTo($list)
}
$lastRow.append("<td data-value='" + value + "'>" + "<b>" + value + " Id = " +Idans  + "</b>" + "</td>")
$(this).remove();
})
```

got my answer from this anyone who might be need future guess